# Why would system() use 100% CPU inside the fork() syscall?

Tags: c++, fork, deadlock

I have a case where I create an `ffmpeg ...` command line and execute it with a simple `system()` call. I use that in my tests and I use that call within a *require* to make sure that it returns 0 as expected, I also print the command so I can easily see what ran and failed:

```
std::cerr << "--- command: " << cmd << std::endl;
CATCH_REQUIRE(system(cmd) == 0);  // <-- get stuck inside there
```

Once in a while, that process locks up, using 100% of one CPU core. Looking at where that happens, I found out that it was in the `do_system()` function¹ of the C library at the point where it does a `syscall`. Comparing to the source code, that would be the `FORK ()` call.

```
#ifdef FORK
  pid = FORK ();
#else
  pid = __fork ();
#endif
```

The following is the corresponding assembly found with gdb, i.e.

```
ps -ef | grep process-name
sudo gdb -p <pid>
```

First I used `where` to see the stack. The last call was to `do_system()`.

Then I typed `disassemble` to get this output:

```
   0x00007ffb9274b129 <+361>:   lea    0x1c(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00007ffb9274b12e <+366>:   xor    %esi,%esi
   0x00007ffb9274b130 <+368>:   mov    $0x100011,%edi
   0x00007ffb9274b135 <+373>:   mov    $0x38,%eax
   0x00007ffb9274b13a <+378>:   syscall 
=> 0x00007ffb9274b13c <+380>:   cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
   0x00007ffb9274b142 <+386>:   ja     0x7ffb9274b2d0 <do_system+784>
   0x00007ffb9274b148 <+392>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x00007ffb9274b14a <+394>:   mov    %eax,%edi
   0x00007ffb9274b14c <+396>:   mov    %eax,0x1c(%rsp)
   0x00007ffb9274b150 <+400>:   je     0x7ffb9274b3c7 <do_system+1031>
```

First, when I saw that I tried to continue to see what happens. I typed the following:

```
gdb> stepi
```

and it went back to 100% CPU usage for one core and never stopped again. Since I was running as root, I'm pretty confident that the `stepi` would function even inside the C library code.

I could understand some form of lock up in the C library, especially since I use threads (although at the point only the main thread is running, the other threads are all exiting before I call `system()`), but I have a hard time understanding why it would block inside the kernel `fork()` syscall.

Anyone encountered such a lock up before who would know why it occurs?

---

Update: Dec 29, 2022

Today I ran in this issue again. The `system()` call I make is from a test, but not within the `CATCH_REQUIRE()` macro. Yet it blocks every single time.

There are two things which I think are important in that version:

1. the tool I run is, on purpose, aborting (it calls `std::terminate()` and is there to verify that it does make that call);
2. the test fails every single time when run from the coverage executable, which includes `gcov` instrumentation (`-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -pg`) along sanitizer compiler extensions (`-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=enum -fsanitize=unreachable`)

I think that combo just kills the whole thing, somehow, with some form of *conflict* which makes the `fork()` function think that it should wait on a lock which it can never obtain. That's my take. Not a real solution one way or the other.

As a side note, this new occurrence is in a test which does not include threading at all. It's a single main process.

Another detail, typing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop the test does nothing. It just sits there (which is further proof that the test is stuck in kernel land). However, doing a `kill <pid>` from another terminal works just fine. So I can still kill my process normally, but not with the keyboard.

---

Update: Dec 31, 2022

Just in case, I thought I would try to run the same code under a VirtualBox install with Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-56-generic) instead of my host machine running Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-200-generic). I already ran the tests three times and each time it worked just fine.

I think that was a kernel bug which got fixed in the last 4 years.

---

¹ *see under sysdeps/posix/system.c (libc version 2.27 under Ubuntu 18.04)*

Comment: 100% of CPU or 100% of 1 core?

Comment: Just curious how did you find `do_system` is where CPU cycles are being spent. Did you use `perf top` or something similar?

Comment: @bolov, 100% of one core.

Comment: @brokenfoot, I used gdb (`ps -ef | grep process-name`, with the pid I do: `gdb -p <pid>`). The `where` commands tells you the function name and the `disassemble` shows you the code as shown above.

Comment: you should [edit] the question to include all this information

Comment: how are the `FORK` and `CATCH_REQUIRE` macros implemented?  Do they include any kind a loop?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know it's really hard to believe, but the CPU loop/lock is happening inside the `syscall`, not in my code or catch2 or anything of the sort. It's inside Kernel land. What the `CATCH_REQUIRE()` is likely adding are signal and exception handlers ([signal(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), `try`/`catch`). What the gcov adds are just counters, I don't think that affects the issue. The sanitizer, however, may also use CPU extensions that are not normally in use...

Answer (score 1):

If fork were to block, it would be taking 0% CPU, not 100%.  So what you have here is almost certainly a tight loop calling fork repeatedly.  Since the fork system call is (probably) the most expensive single thing in the loop, most of the time when you attach or probe with gdb, it will see it as being in the system call.

What you need to do is look at the context (the call scope(s) on the stack) to figure out what the tight loop that keeps calling fork is.

Comment: Note that it rarely happens. Usually when I have had an error earlier (I use catch2 so there are try/throw/catch in there too) and thinking about it, maybe I should not put that inside the `CATCH_REQUIRE()`... Anyway, I have some output before & after the `system()` call, so I would see output going like crazy if it returned and looped over. Finally, I'll do an edit because I also tried `stepi` and it was stuck. If it wasn't stuck inside the `fork()`, the `stepi` would have returned pretty much immediately.